# Oracle APEX plugin, use p_region.source with page_item to get result

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I would like to develop an Oracle APEX plugin. This should do a database query using page_item. Therefore I use p_region.source. Normally you use apex_plugin_util.get_data for this.

I had hoped that I could use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE p_region.source INTO VAR1 VAR2 VAR3`. because it is only a single value query. Unfortunately, this does not work.

I also want to build another SELECT around p_region.source but I can't get any further. Before (no use of a page-item) I simply used `SELECT ... INTO ... WHERE` in the plsql plugin region.

Do you have any tips for me?

Comment: I would ask this in forums.oracle.com instead - I have not see any answers here about plugin specific questions.

Comment: good idea ^^ :D